# WorkDay Human_Resources API Integration

Tags: c#, api, integration, workday-api

I have successfully integrated both Human_Resources and Financial_Management using asp.net C#. So I'm putting all together all the issues I had experienced and helpful resources I found online:

WorkDay Documentation is available at:
https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/index.html

To get started, read here http://hr.dovetailsoftware.com/gcox/2014/06/13/getting-started-workday-web-services-using-c/ make sure to follow some cleanup tips on this article.

If you get the same error while submitting data to WD

> Error

```
There was an error in serializing one of the headers in message Get_ProjectsInput: ‘Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0030: Cannot convert type ‘ConsoleApplication1.WkDay.Rm.Asset_Book_Rule_Request_CriteriaType’ to ‘ConsoleApplication1.WkDay.Rm.Asset_Book_Rule_Request_ReferencesType’
error CS0030: Cannot convert type ‘ConsoleApplication1.WkDay.Rm.Asset_Shares_Request_CriteriaType’ to ‘ConsoleApplication1.WkDay.Rm.Asset_Shares_Request_ReferenceType’
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type ‘ConsoleApplication1.WkDay.Rm.Asset_Book_Rule_Request_ReferencesType’ to ‘ConsoleApplication1.WkDay.Rm.Asset_Book_Rule_Request_CriteriaType’
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type ‘ConsoleApplication1.WkDay.Rm.Asset_Shares_Request_ReferenceType’ to ‘ConsoleApplication1.WkDay.Rm.Asset_Shares_Request_CriteriaType’
‘. Please see InnerException for more details.
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to ask?

Comment: not actually a question. just sharing what I did to make workday intergration work. Does StackOverflow has something like that kind of section? I should move this post there.

Comment: @AlfredRoa please put the solution in the answer section below, separate from the question (then you can accept it as the solution, which marks the question as solved)

Answer (score 3):

Comment out

`[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Request_References", typeof(), Order=0)]`

```html
/// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Request_Criteria", typeof(Asset_Book_Rule_Request_CriteriaType), Order=Asset_Book_Rule_Request_ReferencesType0)]
    //anr [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Request_References", typeof(), Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemElementName")]
    public Asset_Book_Rule_Request_CriteriaType Item
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemField = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I built a C# WCF client for Workday and I am finding that each request takes about 90 seconds weather I am getting 1 record or 100 records. Has anyone else experienced this kid of slowness?

Answer (score 2):

Working with Workday WS v32.1, this is still an issue but the solution applies.

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Request_Criteria", typeof(Asset_Book_Rule_Request_CriteriaType), Order = 0)]
//[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Request_References", typeof(Asset_Book_Rule_Request_ReferencesType), Order = 0)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemElementName")]
        public Asset_Book_Rule_Request_CriteriaType Item
        {
            get { return this.itemField; }
            set { this.itemField = value; }
        }
```